# Votos para fechar perguntas

Tags: debate, fechamento, razões-fechamento

Eu venho percebendo uma atitude, que por vezes, muito apressada. O que ta acontecendo, e isso é bem recorrente, é que algumas perguntas por obterem pouco esclarecimento em sua descrição, já são votadas para serem fechadas. Entendo que as vezes o usuário não coloca mais informações em sua pergunta por n motivos... Mas ao invés de votar diretamente pra fechar, porque não alertá-lo que devido a pouca informação sua pergunta pode ser fechada ? Como tenho visto diversas vezes com usuários novos, um comentário de alguém da comunidade informando sobre o tour do site e tal.

Um exemplo disso [é nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/59226/leitura-obj-e-octree) em que o usuário é novo, e ao invés de orientá-lo, já estão votando pra fechar...

Isso na minha opinião, só faz com que o usuários novos se assustem com o site e não voltem mais..

Não sei se tem algum outro tópico abordando o assunto, mas queria saber a opinião da comunidade sobre isso...

Devemos fechar de primeira ou alertar o usuário, seja ele novo ou não, pra melhorar sua pergunta ?

Entendo que alguns casos o melhor é fechar a pergunta, mas não acho justo fechar uma pergunta que pode ser modificada e ter mais descrição do problema assim logo de primeira.

Comment: Relacionado: [Sem comentários](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2002/3117); [Devemos ser mais tolerantes com novos usuários?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2035/3117)  ; e [Quanto tempo esperar antes de votar para fechar uma pergunta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/537/3117)

Comment: Acho uma discussão válida, também vejo com muita frequência isso ocorrendo.

Comment: Pois é @Math, penso que essa atitude pode fazer com que um usuário novo se assuste e não queira mais voltar ao SOpt, por não entender como funciona. Ao contrário seria para um usuário que tenha um pouco mais de vivência que lidaria com isso de forma mais tranquila.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Uma coisa que acho que ainda não ficou clara para a maioria que está começando no site, perguntas *Pendentes* (ou *Suspensas*) e *Fechadas* não são perguntas *Banidas* e nem *Deletadas*, são perguntas que podem ser editadas e reabertas **se necessário**, em outras palavras, *Fechar* e *Suspender* não são coisas ruins.

### Porque devemos fechar

Um tutorial de como podemos analisar e melhorar se uma pergunta sua foi fechada:

- O primeiro passo é tentar editar melhorando, sem encher de texto desnecessário e tentar *deixar claro* o problema, ou então é falta de código claro, não basta jogar todo código, nesse momento (se já não o fiz) tento [criar um exemplo melhor que as pessoas possam executar facilmente para entender aonde esta o problema](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
- Se já editou e continua fechada geralmente podem haver comentários na publicação que explicam o problema, eu geralmente comento em forma de pergunta a um usuário especifico que já comentou na minha pergunta (usando o `@nome-do-usuario`). Lembre-se se você não usar o `@` a pessoa que você está comentando não irá receber a resposta na **inbox** dele, então após o possível entendimento, edito de novo.
- Se ninguém comentou e eu você ainda não entendeu o porque do fechamento, então pode abrir uma questão no Meta, usando a tag [pergunta-específica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pergunta-espec%c3%adfica)
- Se a pergunta não é sua, você pode comentar para o autor da pergunta, dando-lhe dicas.

### Bom senso

Claro que antes de editar uma pergunta, você deve ter bom senso para não sair simplesmente adicionando texto a pergunta e ainda sim não deixar claro ou objetivo o problema que enfrenta, muitas perguntas as vezes não tem como salvar. Portanto não basta editar, tem que fazer com responsabilidade.

### Pergunta camaleão

As vezes a sua pergunta não é tão ruim e até pode ser salva, se uma boa edição for feita, mas as vezes o autor acaba por descaracterizar totalmente o sentido da pergunta, fazendo com que possíveis respostas já existentes fiquem sem sentido algum ou autor praticamente acaba fazendo outra pergunta que pouco tem haver com a original (acho que muito aqui já sofreram com isto).

### Pergunta fechada/suspensa e edição

Com já citei este tipo de situação não quer dizer que você não possa *reabrir* a pergunta depois de editar, quando você edita a pergunta aparece para usuário mais experientes e eles votam por **reabrir** ou **manter fechada**, isto pode levar um bom tempo pois depende dos usuários da comunidade, se a sua edição não reabriu a pergunta após este tempo é por que você (o autor) não conseguiu deixar claro.

Para concluir sou a favor de fechar, pois fechar não é excluir, em outras palavras fechamento ou suspensão não são coisas ruins.

### Tipos de fechamentos mais comuns

No rodapé da pergunta, aparece o motivo do fechamento/suspensão.

Perguntas que geralmente podem ser reabertas:

- **Não é claro o que você está perguntando** - geralmente pode ser reaberta se o autor melhorar a pergunta, seguindo dicas do [**Help**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking).
- **Essa pergunta não pertence ao site porque não está em Português** - o autor pode editar e escrever a pergunta em Português, então se estiver dentro do escopo será reaberta.
- **Amplo demais** - É difícil reabrir este tipo de pergunta, mas em alguns raros casos o autor pode conseguir melhorar a pergunta e eventualmente ela ser reaberta.
- **Esse problema não pode ser reproduzido, ou é um erro de digitação** - Este tipo geralmente não é reaberta, mas pode ocorrer (raramente) do autor melhorar a pergunta e colocar um foco ou torna-la útil a comunidade, então neste caso talvez seja reaberta.
- **Principalmente baseadas em opiniões** - Este tipo é praticamente impossível ser reaberta, com exceção de raras vezes que o autor de uma resposta nesta pergunta ou a própria pergunta se fazem útil a comunidade (já vi acontecer).

Perguntas que não são reabertas:

- **Essa pergunta não parece ser sobre programação** - Não é um tipo de pergunta para a comunidade, as vezes outras comunidades do StackExchange podem aceitar a pergunta (aquele momento que falamos "cadê o SUpt?" rs).
- **Duplicata de...** - Este tipo de pergunta não pode ser reaberta, pois já existe uma ou mais perguntas com resposta, porém há raras situações que o autor consegue provar que não é uma *duplicata exata* e que as respostas das outras perguntas não respondem a pergunta dele.

Comment: Eu entendi seu ponto de vista @GuilhermeNascimento, que fechar e/ou suspender não seria a exclusão, mas por exemplo, para um usuário novo, fechar a pergunta antes mesmo de colocar um comentário para que ele melhore seria um pouco assustador não ? Coisa que para um usuário mais experiente já seria mais fácil de lidar, pois ele já conhece mesmo que seja o mínimo de como o SOpt funciona...

Comment: @ÉrikThiago o próprio autor da pergunta não pode "fechar", acho que você quer dizer "deletar", deletar é uma situação totalmente diferente, eu vejo assim o autor é dono da pergunta ele pode deletar quando bem entender, se você achou a pergunta interessante e tem uma reposta para ela e tem certeza que o autor não vai desfazer o "deletar", então você pode refazer a pegrunta e ao mesmo tempo postar uma resposta, isto pode lhe garantir pontos na pergunta, tanto quanto na resposta, lembre-se perguntas deletadas são "ocultadas", portanto não são publicas.

Comment: Perdão, o "fechar" que eu me referi, foi aos votos que a pergunta recebeu, e não propriamente ao usuário fechar a pergunta. Então reformulando: "os votos da comunidade para fechar a pergunta antes mesmo de colocar um comentário para que ele melhore seria um pouco assustador não ?"

Comment: Então @ÉrikThiago é isso mesmo que eu quis dizer na minha resposta, é melhor *fechar* algo que está errado para "educar o autor" e previnir uma pergunta fora do escopo receber respostas antes de estar dentro dos padrões, a autor melhorando a pergunta e ela sendo reaberta, o fluxo normal poderá continuar.

Comment: Entendi, e olhando por esse ponto de vista faz sentido fechar e/ou suspender antes que apareça resposta do tipo "eu acho que", como o @JorgeB mencionou em sua resposta. Mas isso me gera um ponto que pode assustar o usuário novo.

Comment: @ÉrikThiago Sim eu concordo, por não ser claro assusta, já foi motivo de discução, veja a minha resposta a está pergunta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2374/3635 isto é um problema com as traduções, infelizmente por algum BOM motivo o pessoal parou de fazer as traduções, acho que é devido a mudanças constantes no layout.

Answer (score 10):

Pelo que eu tenho visto desse tipo de perguntas, a primeira coisa a fazer(na minha opinião) é fechar mesmo, senão acabam por surgir respostas do tipo "acho que". O que vai fazer com que a pergunta dificilmente tenha salvação.

Eu acho que devíamos seguir os seguintes passos:

1. Escrever um comentário pedindo esclarecimento por parte do AP, alertando para o facto da pergunta poder ser fechada (ou será fechada) assim como está e que se ele editar a pergunta esta poderá ser reaberta.
2. Se for o caso, fechar a pergunta antes que comecem a surgir respostas do tipo "acho que".