# Vocês não leem os comentários ou respostas na "fila de analise"?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, comportamento, fechamento, perguntas-fechadas

O titulo é mais um brincadeira, ok? Mas realmente gostaria de saber, no momento que notam alguma coisa na [fila de analise](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review), vocês olham atentamente os comentários?

É a terceira pergunta que noto ser fechada e que particularmente eu discordo, não vou citar todas porque duas já foram resolvidas, mas especificamente esta no momento:

- [Erro "getenv() has been disabled"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203951/3635)

**Quero deixar bem claro** que a mensagem de erro em qualquer que seja o script php ou framework não tem relação com códigos e frameworks:

> Warning: .... has been disabled for security reasons

É um bloqueio nas configuraçãos do `php.ini`, eu expliquei isto na resposta que fiz, ou o problema se resolve editando o `php.ini` ou apenas um administrador de servidor que tem acesso pode editar, **não** tem outra possibilidade, não é um problema com Laravel, é apenas uma configuração do php, nada mais, não há necessidade de detalhamentos e códigos na pergunta.

Ainda sim recebeu votos de fechamento, então fui olhar a fila de analise, ela esta *"quase limpa"*, lembrei-me que o pessoal andou comentando no chat algo como "fila zero", então presumi que o pessoal deve ter colocado algum esforço para cuidar do que faltava, ainda sim pergunto, será que o ideal não é analisar as perguntas incluindo as respostas, mesmo que esteja certo do motivo do fechamento?

Quero dizer no caso especifico é um problema comum e uma dúvida totalmente válida por isto mesmo respondi e não tem outros caminhos, só dois ou você edita o php.ini ou o administrador do servidor edita, não tem como ser ampla.

> Quero deixar claro que houve outros fechamentos em situação semelhante

Então lhes pergunto novamente, o ideal não é olhar com um pouco mais de atenção aos comentários da pergunta (que são visíveis na fila) no minimo?

Comment: Hmmmmmmmmmm... não.

Comment: Acho a fila de análise um tédio.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez também acho, não a frequento mais a muito tempo mesmo.

Comment: Parei de contribuir nas análises há mais de um ano. Mas recentemente percebi muitas perguntas, 100% válidas, fechadas. Isso vem aumentando  desde Abril. Algumas pedi para reabrir e foram reabertas. Outras foram pro lixo (abandoned removed closed).. Na lista dos que votam para fechar, vejo nomes incomuns, provavelmente gente nova no site.

Comment: @DanielOmine percebi isto também, assim como ando notando um aumento de respostas em perguntas que tem bastante dups, também vindo desdes usuários mais novos no site. Ando meu que pegando no pé deles e pedindo apoio de alguns veteranos, mas o pessoal não tem levado a sério ou tem achado que é exagero de minha parte.

Answer (score 2):

Comentários são efêmeros e podem ter uma alta rotatividade. Toda pergunta deve ser capaz de se sustentar por conta própria, sem a necessidade de comentários.

Quando a pergunta é fechada, ela é marcada como *pendente*, não como *obliterada*. Se ela for editada enquanto pendente e com isso ficar boa o suficiente para o modelo do site, ela pode ser reaberta - e vai inclusive para uma fila de revisão própria para isso.

Comment: Olha obrigado pela opinião, mas eu tanto quanto qualquer um entendo bem o sistema de fechamento (como eu mesmo respondi em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2676/3635),  o que estou afirmando aqui é que a pergunta ao meu ver é sim sustentável devido ao que conheço do problema, pois não é algo em códigos e frameworks é uma coisa simples que só tem *duas respostas* possíveis para a pergunta especifica, independente da tecnologia extra que usou. Eu não citei as outras duas perguntas que foram fechadas, mas o fechamento delas também foi errado tanto que o pessoal reviu e reabriu elas...

Comment: ... O que eu estou dizendo é que eu geralmente coloco o motivo para clarear nos comentários se noto um voto de fechamento dizendo o motivo do porque discordo e o pq acho que a pergunta se "sustenta", mas aparentemente parece que algumas pessoas não tem lido ou dado atenção. PS: Apenas opinião minha, nada contra a opinião de ninguem.

Comment: Eu revi a pergunta específica e votei para reabrir. *Mea Culpa:* eu fui um dos fechadores.

Comment: muito obrigado pelo retorno e pela compreensão :D