# AP mudou completamente o foco da pergunta após respostas, o que fazer?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, comportamento

A pergunta em questão é esta:

- [Uma expressão regular pode se transformar em assembly?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/240058/64969)

A pergunta na revisão original estava conforme os estados 1 e 2:

- estado 2: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/240058/2

> a diferença entre os estados 1 e 2 foi um pedantismo de tags

A pergunta inicialmente tinha 3 parágrafos, todos foram extremamente trucidados na edição.

Ao meu ver, a pergunta está agora fora do escopo do site. Citação do estado atual (5):

> Observação: Não busco respostas e sim referências. Pois, o próprio estudo é tão maior e necessariamente exigente quanto qualquer resposta que pode ser dada onde é o exigido mínimo compreender e entender.

Além do mais, a [resposta do @Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/240078/64969) trata boa parte como resposta à dúvida principal da edição atual e da primeira edição. A [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/240086/64969) trata de diversos pontos secundários da edição inicial e da edição nova.

Então, minha dúvida: o que fazer com ela agora? Sinalizar para fechamento, reverter ou continuar com a pergunta no jeito atual? Devemos também, no caso da reversão, devemos sugerir que ele abra uma nova pergunta?

---

A sexta versão parece mais próxima da versão original. Não sei se meu questionamento para essa questão em específica continua válido dado esse novo fator. Mas talvez valha para saber como nos comportar em um momento futuro em situações parecidas?

Comment: A pergunta já estava confusa no inicio, e depois da edição ficou mais confusa ainda, portanto que eu votei como não clara, mas, pode ser fora de escopo ou ampla. Se o AP conseguir ser mais claro e consertar a pergunta, ela poderia ficar aberta, mas por enquanto, eu sugiro que você deixe as coisas seguir em frente e deixe sua resposta lá, ela é útil para outras pessoas.

Comment: Merecendo um rollback, eu vi as edições e quase o fiz, mas nao tive certeza por não dominar o tema.

Comment: Eu acho isso já abuso mesmo, brincar com que quer ajudar outras pessoas a superar as suas dificuldades. Uma das edições foi quase uma nova pergunta, uma vez que o texto foi reescrito a 100%.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Bem vindo ao mundo SOpt*, quase todos nós no site passamos por isto, por isso que eu mesmo parecendo uma vitrola quebrada, fico repetindo, se a pergunta esta um pouco vaga que seja, usem o voto de fechamento.

Mesmo que você acredite ter entendido, se tiver um vestígio de duvida é bem capaz de você estar gastando tempo e talvez venha a descobrir posteriormente que a sua resposta não era o que o AP necessitava.

Entendam que fechamento não é punição, não é deletar, não é banimento, não é nada disso, é apenas uma maneira de evitar esforço em respostas enquanto a pergunta tiver problemas, claro que existem situações que não tem salvamento, como disse em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2676/3635, mas isso é outra história.

Agora eu sempre sigo uma regra, mesmo que não tenha sido eu quem respondeu, se o autor mudar o sentido da pergunta depois de receber respostas, geralmente porque resolveu uma parte e agora tem um novo problema, presumo que o correto é você fazer a **Reversão** da edição para o estado original e se possível comentar e orientar o AP a abrir uma nova pergunta explicando junto com isto o conceito do do site como por exemplo https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Agora se o autor começou com uma pergunta e na verdade ele queria pergunta outra coisa totalmente diferente, por exemplo falou sobre *JavaScript* ou deu a entender isto, mas a pergunta era sobre *Java*, neste caso penso que deveriam fechar a pergunta, se acaso não tiver sido clareada ainda e acaso já tenha explicado melhor o problema as respostas devem ser editadas ou removidas, afinal responder algo prematuramente que pode ter algo que leve a mais de um entendimento nem deveria receber respostas (na maioria dos casos), isto porque geralmente é trabalho desnecessário.

Comment: É, acho que esse foi meu grande batismo aqui. Obrigado pelo _Bem vindo ao mundo SOpt_

Comment: Por nada, 2 casos que talvez você já passou ou ainda vai passar que são verdadeiras provações são: Os trolls (geralmente haters) e os que ficam desfazendo suas edições, porque acham que ninguém pode mexer na postagem deles. Teve um colega do site que ficou em um duelo de edições com um AP... Se não passou por estes dois o seu batismo só está começando jovem guerreiro.

Comment: Duelo de edições! Essa é a nova para mim, mas gostava de ter visto!

Comment: @Isac gostei do nome `Duelo de edições`, eu baixo o mago da edição de olhos vermelhos, ae o cara usa o `devolva pra sua mão das trevas`. Yugioh

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Então e como acabou o duelo ? lol, agora fiquei curioso

Comment: Duelo de edições é como Yugioh, tem dias que vc ganha, tem dias que você perde, tem dias que você desiste porque não tem paciencia. Tem um especifico que não foi comigo, mas muita gente da comunidade viu, se eu achar o link te mando.

Comment: Teve um duelo de edições que o usuário tentou alterar as respostas e a sua própria pergunta para uns textos sem sentidos, como "AAAADKFODUSNFKVO". O duelo foi interrompido pelo Gabe, eu acho, marcando como _conflito de conteúdo_

Comment: Isso sim foi uma edit war: Reddit Place /r/place - TIMELAPSE - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XnRCZK3KjUY

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado um duelo de edições e reversões: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/242578/3635

Comment: @Isac veja o comentário anterior

Comment: @MiguelAngelo veja o comentário anterior

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, guerra de edição é osso! Muita infantilidade

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Afinal a lenda é verdadeira! lol