# Marcar como pendente ou pedir informação nos comentários?

Tags: debate

Recentemente eu vejo várias perguntas sendo marcadas como pendente por não serem claras o suficiente. Algumas perguntas realmente fogem ao escopo do site, porém outras basta uma formatação no código ou esclarecer qual o erro que o código está gerando para que a pergunta seja respondida.

A minha dúvida é: é preciso realmente marcar uma pergunta como pendente mesmo que só falte algo trivial a ser acrescentado?

Comment: Caro Enzo, fechado/pendente não é banimento e nem puxão de orelha, a principio parece algo ruim, mas não é, é para evitar problemas, quase qualquer pergunta pode ser reaberta a qualquer momento, desde que o AP ajuste-a, então entre fechar e reabrir é apenas um pequeno processo burocratico que vai acontecer uma vez ou outra com suas perguntas, se você entender bem aonde falhou dificilmente vai passar por isto novamente, então não tem porque se chatear se uma pergunta sua foi fechada, se aprendeu aonde falhou isso provavelmente não irá ocorrer em novas perguntas [...]

Comment: [...] O Fechamento é benéfico a "comunidade" para evitar problemas, pois evita que alguém responda algo errado por falta de algum detalhe da pergunta. Formulei uma resposta inteira sobre o assunto: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2676/3635 ... Esse é um assunto já debatido MUITAS VEZES, não tem porque ficarmos martelando ele, basta ler postagens antigas do Meta, tem mais de uma, com certeza irá entender o porque das coisas serem assim, as atitudes da comunidade não são aleatórias, tudo tem um motivo para manter o bom funcionamento. Boa sorte ;)

Comment: Não aconteceu comigo, tanto é que nunca fiz nenhuma pergunta no Stack Overflow em Português. Como eu sou mais ativo no Stack Overflow original e não vejo muitas perguntas serem marcadas como pendente a não ser em casos em que o assunto da pergunta foge completamente ao assunto do site, então estranhei. Na minha opinião é uma medida desnecessária, nada que um comentário pedindo esclarecimento não resolva.

Comment: Eu vejo muitas perguntas serem fechadas no SOen, muitas mesmo, talvez passe batido para alguns, lá a comunidade de moderadores e colaboradores é bem maior e por este motivo talvez você não tenha notado, porque as coisas saem e voltam (são corrigidas pelos APs) antes mesmo que você note. Aqui as é um pouco mais devagar, mas o processo é o mesmo.

Comment: Essa sensação de desnecessário na verdade é porque você esta vendo isso tudo como usuário apenas do site, não tem atuado nem no SOen e nem aqui como colaborador ativo para resolver problemas da comunidade (não falo de responder perguntas), como "fila de analise" ou orientar pessoas de como melhorarem suas postagens, conforme você começar a fazer isso vai se tornar natural o entendimento dos problemas que perguntas deficientes de algo podem ser potencialmente problemáticas e que essa burocracia do fechamento [...]

Comment: [...] e reabertura foi pensado e replanejado diversas vezes desde 2008 (quando o site foi lançado), e que milhares de pessoas em todas comunidades SO de certa forma notaram aonde isto poderia ser melhorado e a necessidade de isto funcionar exatamente como é hoje, não basta usar eventualmente o site para notar isso, apenas ainda é obscuro para ti, mas lhe garanto tudo tem suas motivações. Boa sorte.

Comment: Se foi fechada, provavelmente, o que faltou não era tão trivial assim. Erros podem acontecer e ela ser fechada injustamente, mas a pergunta pode ser reaberta

Comment: Apenas para efeito de comparação, entre 1 de janeiro e hoje, o SOen [fechou mais de 43 mil perguntas](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1054820) (cerca de 2% do total) enquanto o SOpt fechou [cerca de 1000 perguntas](https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/1054819) (cerca de 4% do total). Talvez vc não veja muitas perguntas fechadas lá porque em termos percentuais é pouco (e a avalanche de perguntas diárias pode acabar "encobrindo" isso). Já aqui, com um número menor em termos absolutos, mas o dobro em termos percentuais, a impressão pode ser de que há mais fechamentos...

Answer (score 5):

Sim, o fechamento é importante, principalmente porque alguns usuários por uma razão ou outra (alguns porque querem pontos de qualquer jeito) respondem algo que não dá para responder adequadamente e fica um conteúdo de baixa qualidade ali. Se este comportamento não ocorresse poderíamos até tentar segurar um pouco, mas já tentamos, eu mesmo no começo defendia não fechar imediatamente, mas com o tempo foi piorando tudo e agora a melhor solução é fechar logo e reabri se foi resolvido. Minha experiência é que na maioria das vezes não é corrigido de forma aceitável.

Além disto o Guilherme falou de vários pontos que não são o foco da pergunta mas que ajudam entender melhor o fechamento.

Se alguém está fechando por causa de formatação de código ruim está fazendo algo errado. Esclarecer o erro é o ponto fundamental que deveria estar na pergunta.

O SOen é grande demais, e as pessoas cansaram, aqui estamos cansando, mas ainda temos disposição em cuidar disso, lá já é mais comum as pessoas mais ativas nem entrarem em perguntas ruins, por perderem tempo com elas. Fechar geralmente gera algum comprometimento que as pessoas cada vez querem menos. Mas lá ainda tem muita coisa fechada, é só pegar estatísticas. O fato de você não ver muitas entre as várias milhares de perguntas novos diárias não quer dizer que não aconteça. **Talvez** aqui seja pior, tem muito casos por aqui de pessoas completamente sem noção de programação, ou até de comunicação ou de vivência na internet.

Então entendo sua preocupação, mas a experiência de quem está aqui todo dia é outra.

Vou aproveitar para dizer uma coisa que tenho notado. Muitas perguntas estão colocando o que querem fazer de forma muito geral, em forma muito parecida, ainda que disfarçada de enunciado (não estou dizendo que são exercícios, mas isto não importa, o problema não é ser exercício é a pessoa querer um solução inteira pronta), em muitos casos ela coloca o resultado final do que deseja, e até em parte desses casos colocam o código que ela começou fazer, o que faz algumas pessoas acharem que a pergunta está boa, mas na verdade aquele código não faz nada do que ela está querendo, é um código anterior, paralelo, colateral, preparatório, ela ainda quer que faça tudo para ela. Estes casos encorajo as pessoas ajudaram se puderem para que ela coloque algo que realmente fez, que muda para uma pergunta mais específica, um problema real, porém a pergunta ainda deve ser fechada até que seja mudada para algo que tenha um dúvida real e não seja só um pedido de entregar o código que ela não sabe nem por onde começar. Curiosamente algumas pessoas confessam isso logo de cara, talvez achando que as pessoas terão mais empatia desta forma.

E acho que deveríamos ter uma forma de responder para pessoas que não sabem por onde começar, mas isto é outro debate e não sei se tem solução boa, acredito que sejam perguntas úteis se forem muito bem feitas, o que em geral a pessoa não sabe fazer.