# Várias perguntas marcadas como fora do escopo

Tags: debate, suporte

Tenho observado no site que várias perguntas dentro do escopo de programação estão sendo fechadas como "fora de escopo", em alguns casos vejo como algo errado, como nos exemplos a seguir:

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/434523/csharp-erro-cs1525

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/434385/renderizar-preview-de-impress%C3%A3o-escpos-em-aplicativo-xamarim-forms-android

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/434118/sequencia-do-cadeado

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/434004/manipulando-dados-do-excel-com-epplus-c

[Agrupar itens por mês e ordenar por datas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/436145/agrupar-itens-por-m%C3%AAs-e-ordenar-por-datas)

[Erro ASP.NET SecurityException: Request failed](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/423967/erro-asp-net-securityexception-request-failed)

[Como armazenar vários valores em um único campo de uma tabela de um servidor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/436515/como-armazenar-v%C3%A1rios-valores-em-um-%C3%BAnico-campo-de-uma-tabela-de-um-servidor)

[Várias perguntas marcadas como fora do escopo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8213/v%C3%A1rias-perguntas-marcadas-como-fora-do-escopo)

[Inserir um Header no SOAP Header. Delphi XE6](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/436683/inserir-um-header-no-soap-header-delphi-xe6)

Essa é até bizarra, um usuário não conseguiu incluir uma resposta pq ela está fechada:

[ERRO AO EXIBIR DADOS MYSQL EM PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/436682/erro-ao-exibir-dados-mysql-em-php)

Vejo isso há um tempo e não entendo o motivo, essas perguntas estão claramente no escopo da comunidade.

Pergunto isso pois não vejo isso acontecer no SO.

Uma resposta ótima com assunto relacionado: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7175/8545

Quantidade de perguntas abertas:
https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/1194735/perguntas-abertas

Quantidade de perguntas fechadas (Não verifiquei ainda a questão da qualidade, ainda estou vendo uma forma de executar uma avaliação isenta):
https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/1194734/perguntas-fechadas

Temos um problema de qualidade? Temos, mas sempre precisamos fechar como "fora do escopo"?

Como resolver o problema da qualidade das perguntas?
[Baixa qualidade em perguntas de novatos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7165/baixa-qualidade-em-perguntas-de-novatos)

Será que estamos atacando o problema da maneira correta?

Comment: A pergunta que adicionou a lista foi fechada por dois motivos. Primeiro que não faz sentido, o AP diz querer ordenar por datas mas a saída pretendida na verdade apenas duplica o primeiro item do array. Segundo que não é uma pergunta é uma atividade do tipo [Façam Para Mim](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5486#5486) que foge ao escopo do site.

Comment: @Diogo mas te pergunto, a pessoa apresentou um código ou apresentou algo que ela quer que façamos? Se o escopo do site é resolver códigos existentes ou explicar funcionalidades de APIs e softwares voltados para programação, apresentar um algo sem código que sugere o tipo "façam pra mim" (falo só da pergunta *"Agrupar itens por mês e ordenar por datas"*) não se enquadraria, mas pra resolver bastaria ele mostrar alguma tentativa, que funcione parcialmente ou não, e provavelmente ela nem teria sido fechada, como eu disse, quase todos fechamentos podem ser reabertos ;)

Comment: PS: esta nova ultima pergunta sobre `<trust` já tem 2 comentários na pergunta, o primeiro é um bom motivo o segundo melhor ainda, porque este bloqueio esta além de códigos, é provavel que só o suporte técnico da hospedagem resolva, ou que ele mude a estratégia de código, e como não foi apresentado código não temos como dizer alternativas, se tivesse código e alternativas não fossem possiveis, obrigando o uso de trust, ainda sim seria off, pq é algo a nivel de infraestrutura, o bloqueio é na hospedagem, só o suporte deles pode resolver (resposta editada, com maiores detalhes ;))

Comment: @Diogo acho que vc precisa dar uma lida no [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70) - Perceba que tem muitas perguntas feitas todo dia e positivadas e com boas respostas. Se não é o caso da sua, o provável problema é na postagem, simples entender isso. O Guia pode te ajudar a fazer igual o pessoal que tem sucesso, para não ficar na turma que "empaca". Tem muitos fazendo papel de bobo nos comentários pelo site, e são os que só reclamam. O Guia foi feito para ajudar a não cair nessa roubada, com soluções concretas. Espero que ele ajude.

Comment: @Censurado, será que tem como pegar o número de vezes que cada usuário fechou uma pergunta e ordenar isto? Fiquei curioso agora. Pesquisei por cima aqui mas não vi como.

Comment: @Dherik acho que tem sim, é só brincar lá é bem fácil. Tipo isso => https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/edit/1199446

Comment: @Dherik mas não tire conclusões em cima desses dados crus.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Caro Diego primeiramente leia https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2676/3635, isso eu tentei explicar cada tipo de fechamento, acho que o Maniero já explicou os motivos de cada, mas vou separar em tópicos:

1. [csharp erro CS1525](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/434523/3635)

   É esse de digitação do autor da pergunta (chamamos de `AP`), ele fez `if(salario > 2000.0 || <= 2800.0)` quando deveria ser isto `if(salario > 2000.0 || salario <= 2800.0)`, erros de digitação raramente (ou nunca) ajudam futuros visitantes, portanto não tem sentido em manter algo que é um erro ao digitar.
2. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/434385/3635

   Dá pra sugerir palpites nessa, mas não tem como saber se vai funcionar no ambiente dele exatamente, perguntas assim geralmente gastam o tempo de quem responde e geralmente o autor acaba resolvendo mudando a forma que aplicou tudo, o que raramente vai servir para outras pessoas que vem no site pesquisando por problemas semelhantes, pois o problema nesta pergunta é especifico para o autor e provavelmente não se aplica a mais ninguém
3. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/434118/3635

   Aqui provavelmente é trabalho de faculdade ou algo assim, a pessoa provavelmente quer que façamos a lição de casa dele, e eu sou totalmente contra, sou contra *"dar o peixe"*, sou contra ajudar pessoas que não se esforçam a se formarem e gerar péssimos profissionais, o AP não mostrou nenhuma tentativa de aplicar o que aprendeu para tentar resolver, ele só veio e pediu para alguém fazer o que ele não quer
4. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/434004/3635

   Isso é claramente fora do escopo, ele está pedindo dicas para começar a estudar algo e nesse caso o máximo que dá pra fazer é indicar a documentação:

   - https://epplussoftware.com/Developers/
   - https://epplussoftware.com/docs/5.0/articles/readme.html

   E claro ela é fraca, pelo que observei, mas não significa que devemos ficar procurando links a esmo pra formular perguntas que sejam só isso, a pergunta deveria ser de um problema no uso da lib, então seria on-topic, se é um pedido de onde encontrar artigos, documentação e livros, então não é uma pergunta do tópico e não faz sentido ficar aberta
5. [Agrupar itens por mês e ordenar por datas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/436145/3635)

   É parecido com o caso da segunda pergunta, eu até acho correto analisar caso a caso, mas tem casos evidentes de serem o mesmo tipo de situação, o caso ai é simples, o autor não tentou nada, ele só chegou aqui esperando que nós sejamos um tipo de helpdesk e que faremos o trabalho dele, a culpa nem é dele totalmente, o site tem um fama de "helpdesk", fora e dentro da comunidade.
6. [Erro ASP.NET SecurityException: Request failed](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/423967/3635)

   A primeira parte da pergunta ele mesmo respondeu, ele tem a solução, mas a solução não funciona porque a hospedagem é bloqueada neste nível, ou seja, não é problema de programação, é problema de INFRA e INFRA não é on-topic, nem tem como ser, pois não podemos atender suporte técnico de hospedagens e servidores específicos, o caso de como resolver o tal problema me parece que é contactando o suporte técnico da hospedagem.

Eu mesmo queria perguntar muita coisa sobre servidores, sobre clusters, sobre banco de dados em servidores e benchmark (na área de bancos e programas), mas esses assuntos que me interessam **são OFF-topic** e por isso eu não pergunto aqui, geralmente eu entro no [CHAT](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha) que é mais para conversação e lá se alguém tiver disposto a me dar uma dica, ótimo, se não paciência.

Comment: Tranquilo, vida que segue, obrigado pelas respostas!

Comment: Apaguei minha resposta, o AP não gostou dela. **Insistiu** que eu estava errado e agora aceita uma resposta que diz a mesma coisa (está mais completa, mas não muda o que eu tinha dito), vai entender. Fora isso teve uma pessoa que não queria que o debate acontecesse, só pode falar o que ela quer ouvir, então encerra o assunto assim, que bom o AP aceitou agora o que eu havia dito antes.

Comment: @Diogo opa, blz! Recomendo que leia sempre a "caixa azul" que fica acima das postagens, lá contêm os detalhes de cada tipo de fechamento e na duvida veja os links que seguem dentro da mesma caixa. Se ainda discordar do fechamento verifique primeiro se a pergunta não se enquadra em nenhum outro tipo de fechamento, pq as vezes foi fechada como um tipo, mas como são 5 votos pra fechar 3 votaram no motivo X e 2 no Y, o Y seria o adequado, então a pergunta deve sim estar fechada, mas só o motivo escolhido estaria errado. Se você acha que não se enquadra em nenhum então pode votar para reabrir.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sim, o problema que estou vendo muitas perguntas fechadas e não vejo um comentário para ajudar o usuário, acredito que isso seja uma forma de espantar a galera que tem dúvida de verdade.

Comment: Alô @Maniero não aceitei a sua pois não estava clara o suficiente, eu ainda acredito que a quantidade de perguntas é um problema. Nada contra você. Já disse inclusive que acho muito importante o seu trabalho aqui. Não estou no SO para ganhar pontos, estou para aprender e para ajudar as pessoas.

Comment: @Diogo isso já foi debate muitas vezes no site, a caixa azul, os links e tudo mais está lá, não somos suporte técnico e nem trabalhamos de graça, colaboramos com o nosso tempo, eu nos meus primeiros meses tive *3 perguntas fechadas* de uma vez, mas eu não sai reclamando, eu li o que a tal caixa (antes era amarela) e comecei a ver como as perguntas que tinham score mais elevado eram formuladas e principalmente eu li o help todo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help ... Cada um pode fazer por si, as pessoas tem que aprender *"ajudar a 'serem' ajudadas"*

Comment: O bom é ver os downvotes na pergunta. Não vou apagar. Pelo que estou vendo os motivos dos fechamentos estão melhores agora. Obrigado @GuilhermeNascimento!

Comment: @Diogo os downvotes no site pt.meta. não indicam score, na verdade só indicam que talvez algumas pessoas discordem de ti, mas que bom que pude ajuda-lo a compreender melhor. Até breve.