# Pergunta fora de escopo

Tags: debate, perguntas

Não consegui entender o motivo dessa [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/449717/como-remover-uma-string-de-uma-multiline-textbox-em-c) estar fora de escopo.

Procurei [aqui no meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8213/v%C3%A1rias-perguntas-marcadas-como-fora-do-escopo) sobre esse assunto e ainda assim não ficou muito claro o motivo de estar `fora de escopo`, acho que foi marcado de forma errada ou entendi errado.

Comment: Uma leitura muito boa, em especial para quem pergunta, é o [Guia de Sobrevivência](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70) do site.

Comment: Algumas observações básicas que todos devem ler e conhecer antes de fazer uma pergunta no site: [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/137387)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**É um enunciado**. A pessoa colocou o problema e esperou que alguém fizesse o código para ela. Isso é fora de escopo, apesar de ser de programação, conforme definido em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Qual é a diferença disso para um exercício feito para entregar em uma faculdade? Não dá para dizer se não é exatamente isso. Mas mesmo que não seja, ainda é a pessoa pedindo para outra fazer para ela.

> È um problema específico de programação?

Não, é um problema, é algo que a pessoa quer fazer. Mas onde está a especificidade? Ele quer que você faça para ela, não existe um problema que ela está tendo no código que ela fez.

> um algoritmo de software

Não, é sobre entregar um código pronto.

> ferramentas comuns entre programadores

Não.

> problemas práticos e bem definidos que dizem respeito ao desenvolvimento de software
>   dúvidas teóricas sobre conceitos e práticas aplicadas ao desenvolvimento de software

Onde está todas informações necessárias? Quem garante que um código postado ali será bom para aquilo? È comum que nem seja o que a pessoa precisa de fato, mas ela sempre será agradecida por alguém postar algo. Para ela pode ser útil, mas outra pessoa virá achará que é bom, copiará e não ser porque não tem informação suficiente.

Obviamente não é uma dúvida teórica.

Então quando é assim, não procure no meta, clique no *link* da descrição do fechamento.

Se ela posta um código que ela tentou fazer, e aí tem um problema, dá para responder. Dá para falar sobre o erro que ela cometeu, dá para fazer sobre um possível de performance, ou segurança, ou vazamento de memória. Existe um contexto de onde vai usar que muda o que deve ser feito, tem mais detalhes ali.

Esse é um caso onde é usado como mural de helpdesk, quem perguntou e quem respondeu ficam satisfeitos, quem vem depois ver a página poderá aprender errado porque falta contexto ali, é só uma receita de bolo. Não é obtivo do Stack Overflow. E mais, as pessoas verão isso e vão achar que aqui é um mural de helpdesk, que é só pedir o que deseja e alguém fará o código para ela, e assim ela fará o mesmo, e logo teremos praticamente só perguntas assim, porque é bastante cômodo para as pessoas pedirem para fazer para elas e alguém fazer.

Comment: Essa parte  "não procure no meta, clique no link da descrição do fechamento" fiz isso e não tinha entendido também, por isso perguntei no Meta. Removi minha resposta da pergunta por concordar com seu texto e ver que de fato faz sentido.

Comment: Aí é com você. Fez bem em perguntar. O meta é para tirar dúvidas mesmo, nem sempre fica claro.

Comment: Por isso eu acho um erro o fim do SO Documentation. Nunca foi bem justificado porque acabou. Lá era um *cookbook*. Era curado pela comunidade, era tudo canônico. Resolvia uma questão dessas.