# Por que perguntas "Fechadas" ainda aparecem na listagem?

Tags: debate, perguntas, perguntas-fechadas

Uma dúvida que me ocorreu ao ver seguidas perguntas com o status de "Fechada" é o porque elas continuam a aparecer na listagem se não podem receber respostas ?
Uma vez fechadas, elas não deveriam aparecer somente para o autor da pergunta afim de que ele a edit ou exclua ?

Comment: Elas ainda podem ser reabertas (mas pra isso eu preciso entrar na pergunta e dar o voto de reabertura), receber orientações nos comentários para que seja editada/melhorada (ou os outros usuários podem fazer estas melhorias, não somente o autor), etc. Por isso faz sentido continuar visível para todos.

Comment: Este voto de reabertura pode ser feito por qualquer um, ou somente pelo op ?

Comment: Esse voto de reabertura só pode ser dado por usuários que já alcançaram o privilégio de [votos para suspende ou reabrir perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions). Privilégio esse obtido com 3000 pontos de reputação.

Comment: [Lista dos privilégios](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).

Comment: E qualquer usuário pode editar e melhorar o post, se tiver meios/conhecimento e vontade de fazê-lo, mesmo de baixa reputação. Além disso, é uma maneira da comunidade avaliar se o fechamento foi correto, e após uma edição verificar se merece reabertura ou não.

Comment: Olá JcSaint, uma pergunta fechada não é o mesmo que deletada ou banida ou proibida, respondi a isso a algum tempo: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2676/3635 --- como "moderador comunitário", que qualquer usuário pode ser, você pode melhorar perguntas fechadas ou orientar aonde elas devem ser melhoradas, pois alguns tipos de fechamento é só questão do AP melhorar a pergunta que ela entrará na fila de analise para que 5 usuários avaliem se a pergunta pode ser reaberta, não precisando da intervenção de moderadores. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>Apenas para sumarizar o que foi ditos nos comentários:</sup>

---

O fechamento não é algo definitivo, pois uma pergunta fechada [pode ser reaberta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2676/112052).

Qualquer um pode clicar na pergunta e avaliar se o fechamento foi correto:

- se acho que o fechamento foi incorreto, dou o voto de reabertura ([caso eu já tenha pontuação suficiente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions))
- se acho que a pergunta pode ser melhorada, posso editá-la (e [ela entra automaticamente na fila de reabertura](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/36423/401803))
- ainda, se eu achar que vale a pena, posso abrir uma pergunta aqui no Meta para discutir o fechamento (e a possibilidade de reabertura), usando a tag [pergunta-específica](/questions/tagged/pergunta-espec%c3%adfica) e colocando um *link* para a mesma
- ou eu posso simplesmente comentar na pergunta, orientando o autor para melhorá-la, explicando que ela pode ser reaberta, etc
- ainda há casos de pessoas "revoltadas" com o fechamento, que começam a editar a pergunta adicionando xingamentos e afins, e nesse caso eu posso [sinalizar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) para a moderação (e reverter as edições, comentar para o autor pedindo que não faça isso, etc)

Para que tudo isso seja possível a qualquer usuário, e não somente ao autor da pergunta, ela precisa continuar visível para toda a comunidade. Lembre-se que [o papel de moderar o site e mantê-lo organizado é de todos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8437/112052).